# Backgrid: Highlight cells, which habe pending edits

Tags: backbone.js, cell, highlight, backgrid

I found totally nothing about this question in all of the forums (also google) so I will try it here.
Is it possible in Backgrid to highlight cells with pending edits? I found something for highlighting rows, which are pending but this doesn't seems to work in newer versions of Backgrid.
Would be nice if somebody could help me in this case.

**Minimal example:**

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var collections = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: model,
  url: "rest/getFilter"
});
var collection = new collections();

var columns = [{
  name:'filterId', label:'ID', cell:'integer', editable:true
},
{
  name:'statement', label:'Statement', cell: 'string', editable:true
}];
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: columns,
  collection: collection
});

$("#processor_filter").append(grid.render().el);
collection.fetch();
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] we can work with?

Comment: Added ;) I want to highlight the cells, which were edited. (Like I descriped in the question above). In the end I'd like to save all edits at once with a save-button and the user should know which cells he edited before saving in a database. But first of all I need that highlight thing